# How do I link from one piece of text to another within a LaTeX document?

Tags: hyperref

How do I link from one piece of text to another within a LaTeX document?

For example I have Sentence:

*This is a sentence based of reference [1].*

```
\begin{sloppypar}
\begin{enumerate}

\item Item 1 text

\end{enumerate}
\end{sloppypar}
```

How do I make my initial sentence (*This is a sentence based of reference [1].*) or/and part of it clickable so it goes down the page to item 1 upon the text in the initial sentence (*This is a sentence based of reference [1].*) being clicked?

I believe I have to use a combination of:

- hyperref
- Assigning a variable name to the item perhaps?

Please could someone show me some example code on how to achieve what I am trying to do.

Please note I have items starting at one in another tex file that makes up the document I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\hyperref` can point to any standard `\label` as \ref`  would do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\hyperref[foo]{This link will jump to the enumerate environment.}
\lipsum
\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{foo}Item 1 text
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly.

Comment: Is there a way to do it circular referred @campa for example link back from the text you came from? It seems messy to use the same method?

Comment: You could write something like `\hyperref[foo]{This link will jump to the enumerate environment.}\hypertarget{backfoo}{}`, and in the enumeration `\item \label{foo}\hyperlink{backfoo}{Back to origin}`. Look for `\hyperlink{}{}`/`\hypertarget{}{}` in the `hyperref` manual.